# Converting from Rails 3.2 to 4.1 and model tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm migrating app from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.1. I have a model User which is written like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #some code
  def to_hash
  end

  def other_method
  end
end
```

And specs for it like `expect(User.last.to_hash).to ...`

Then I'm running specs, it staring failing on

```
/home/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451/gems/activemodel-4.1.0/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:435:in `method_missing': undefined method `to_hash' for #<User:0x0000000c06bc68> (NoMethodError)
```

And if I'll test other methods, it will fail too (but attributes are working properly).

From `rails c` everything is working OK. On Rails 3.2 it was working ok too. What can be wrong?

Comment: puts User.last.send(:to_hash).inspect;
puts User.last.instance_eval {to_hash} 
are working from rails c, but not in rspec.

Comment: I don't know what is inside to_hash method but you might want to use `User.last.attributes`

Comment: @MrYoshiji I need to_hash because I'm using tire and it uses this method. But no one of methods is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, I've found an error. I had code in spec_helper like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  SOME_DATE = 1.day
end
```

And after commenting it everything is ok. I don't know exactly why it stops work of my project.

It was working on 3.2 but not working or 4.1
I need it to stub one constant.